# Vue Firestore query. How to avoid duplication when Firestore updates data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

In an ionic vue app, I want to display some data from a Firebase Firestore in.

In the Firestore, I have a collection `households` with a subcollection `entries`. A user can be a member of a household and I want to display all entries of all households she is a member of.

I have an array `entries` in my `data`:

```
data() {
  return {
    entries: [],
  };
},
```

I fill this array by making three nested queries against firebase:

1. Get current user
2. Get all households associated with current user
3. Get all entries from all households for current user

```
beforeCreate: function () {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      // Get current uid
      let uid = user.uid;

      // Loop trough all households of user
      let userHouseholdIds = [];
      db.collection("households")
        .where("members", "array-contains", uid)
        .onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
          snapshotChange.forEach((doc) => {
            userHouseholdIds.push(doc.id);
          });

          userHouseholdIds.forEach((householdId) => {
            // Get household name
            db.collection("households")
              .doc(householdId)
              .get()
              .then((value) => {
                let householdId = value.id;
                let householdName = value.data().name;

                // Get household entries
                db.collection("households")
                  .doc(householdId)
                  .collection("entries")
                  .onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
                    snapshotChange.forEach((doc) => {
                      let newDoc = doc.data();
                      newDoc["id"] = doc.id;
                      newDoc["householdName"] = householdName;
                      newDoc["householdId"] = householdId;
                      this.entries.push(newDoc);
                    });
                  });
              });
          });
        });
    }
  });
```

Although I'm not sure if this is the way to go, this works as expected (so far).

However, when I make a change in an entry `e1` in a household `h1` directly in the Firestore console, every entry from `h1` gets duplicated in the frontend.

I guess, I need a `this.entries = []` somewhere before an update from Firestore comes in, but I cannot figure out where.

Am I on the right track? What would I need to modify to avoid the duplication?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Julian, could you please check if in Firestore there's also a duplicate entry?

Comment: No, no duplicate entry in the Firestore; after a refresh everything looks like expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have to use 'onSnapshot' check change.type

```
db
.collection(...)
.where(...)
.onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
    snapshotChange.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          this.entries.push()
        } else if (change.type === 'modified') {
          this.entries.splice()
        } else if (change.type === 'removed') {
          this.entries.splice()
        }
      })
})
```

If not, try using get()

```
db
.collection(...)
.where(...)
.get()
```

Comment: Great, that's it!